# Android SDK version is lover than library version

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I can't add android support design library to my project because "This support library should not use different version (26) than the compileSdkVersion (25)". But my android SDK version is 26.0.2. and when i try to change sdk version to 26 in gradle it gives me error. So why Android Studio can't use the latest sdk version? Here is the 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtPOT.png).

Comment: In the future, please post the contents of your `build.gradle` file as *text*, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my android SDK version is 26.0.2

There is nothing in that screenshot with a value of `26.0.2`.

There is a `25.0.2`, and that is your `buildToolsVersion`, which is not your problem.

> So why Android Studio can't use the latest sdk version?

Android Studio can.

Your Gradle build file is attempting to use a *preview* edition of `com.android.support:design`. That specific version, `26.0.0-alpha1`, begins with `26`. The rule with the Support Library is that your `compileSdkVersion` needs to match that major version number of the library. In your case, your `compileSdkVersion` is 25.

The simplest solution for you is to change your `compile` statement to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

This solves two problems:

1. It synchronizes the major version of the library with your `compileSdkVersion`
2. It gets you on a production-ready version of the library, rather than an `alpha1` preview release, tied to the Android O developer preview